# What is a good live-cd distribution that could be used as the base for my linux program?

Tags: linux, distro, live-cd

There is an upcoming programming challenge (forensics challenge) that asks the entrants to write a program that runs on a bootable cd that helps format attached media to that computer.

I'm considering submitting an entry and I'd like to utilize as much existing open-source software as possible.  In fact, I think the programming I'll be doing for this will be mostly writing a GUI wrapper around a couple open source linux utilities.

For the first part, I want to get the bootable CD working and I'm looking to use an existing linux live-cd disrtrobution.
What is a minimal live-cd distribution that would be a good candidate for this usecase?

Considerations:

- Minimal
- Small memory footprint
- Fast boot times

Comment: this will quickly descend into "what's your favourite linux distro", regardless of actual requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I favor slax. It comes as a good package as it is and is pretty slim for its content.

http://www.slax.org/

Answer (score 1):

If you like Ubuntu, you can create your own [custom LiveCD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization). Many other distributions offer this as well. I know that Gentoo also supports creating a custom Live distro.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [SUSE studio](http://susestudio.com/). It's basically a web-based engine that lets you customize your own distro or LiveCD based on SUSE.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is rBuilder:
http://www.rpath.com/corp/

Answer (score 0):

A small linux distribution then you don't get much smaller than [damn small linux.](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/)

Not the best distro about but from your description I don't think you intend to use this for anything other than your challenge. Meets your 3 requirements easily.